# Scala Spark Incrementing a column based on another column in dataframe without for loops

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like the one below. I want a new column called cutofftype - which instead of the current monotonically increasing number should reset to 1 every time the ID column changes .

df = df.orderBy("ID","date").withColumn("cutofftype",monotonically_increasing_id()+1)

```
+------+---------------+----------+
|   ID |    date       |cutofftype|
+------+---------------+----------+
| 54441|     2016-06-20|         1|
| 54441|     2016-06-27|         2|
| 54441|     2016-07-04|         3|
| 54441|     2016-07-11|         4|
| 54500|     2016-05-02|         5|
| 54500|     2016-05-09|         6|
| 54500|     2016-05-16|         7|
| 54500|     2016-05-23|         8|
| 54500|     2016-06-06|         9|
| 54500|     2016-06-13|        10|
+------+---------------+----------+
```

Target is this as below :

```
+------+---------------+----------+
|   ID |    date       |cutofftype|
+------+---------------+----------+
| 54441|     2016-06-20|         1|
| 54441|     2016-06-27|         2|
| 54441|     2016-07-04|         3|
| 54441|     2016-07-11|         4|
| 54500|     2016-05-02|         1|
| 54500|     2016-05-09|         2|
| 54500|     2016-05-16|         3|
| 54500|     2016-05-23|         4|
| 54500|     2016-06-06|         5|
| 54500|     2016-06-13|         6|
+------+---------------+----------+
```

I know this can be done with for loops - i want to do it without for loops >> Is there a way out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple partition by problem. You should use the `window`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date")

df.withColumn("cutofftype", row_number().over(w)).show()


+-----+----------+----------+
|   ID|      date|cutofftype|
+-----+----------+----------+
|54500|2016-05-02|         1|
|54500|2016-05-09|         2|
|54500|2016-05-16|         3|
|54500|2016-05-23|         4|
|54500|2016-06-06|         5|
|54500|2016-06-13|         6|
|54441|2016-06-20|         1|
|54441|2016-06-27|         2|
|54441|2016-07-04|         3|
|54441|2016-07-11|         4|
+-----+----------+----------+
```